# How does std::swap work in terms of constructors, assignment operators, and destructors?

Tags: c++, std, swap

If I have `T a` and `T b` and I call `std::swap(a, b)`, what is the order of copy constructors, assignment operators, and destructors that are called?

Comment: It depends on what is `T`

Comment: How so? Is there not a standard method used to swap two generic objects of some type `T`?

Comment: I meant that there are many specializations, and possibly user defined ones.

Comment: @quantdev: Since it's `std::swap`, it can only call overloads in the `std` namespace, which means it's a known and documented set of types.

Comment: @MooingDuck agreed, user defined ones are out of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific order that is "mandated", it would all depend on the implementation provided by the Standard Library being used.

A C++03 variation of `std::swap` would be:

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T& a, T& b) {
    T temp(a); // copy
    a = b;     // assign
    b = temp;  // assign
}
```

A C++11 implementation would be:

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T& a, T& b) {
    T temp = std::move(a); // move copy or normal copy (moves if moveable)
    a = std::move(b);      // move or assign
    b = std::move(temp);   // move or assign
}
```

Several `std` containers etc. do specialise on `swap` because they can offer better or more efficient implementations; custom types could do the same. In these specialisations, even more variation could or would occur.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no specialisation for `T`, then the generic version will do something along the lines of

```
{
    T t = std::move(a);  // move construction
    a = std::move(b);    // move assignment
    b = std::move(t);    // move assignment
}                        // destruction of t
```

Some types (such as containers) might have specialisations which will swap internal pointers etc., with no temporary object and no object assignment.